# OAuth2 with Telegram login

Tags: oauth-2.0, telegram

I need to implement OAuth2 Authorization on my website. There are 2 opportunities to do this.

1. **Telegram login widget**. I can't use it, because I need to change default button style.
2. **Seamless Telegram login**. There is no redirect url option.
   If anyone done tasks like this, share solution please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your ui element and use https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegram-bot-auth to implement authorisation and then handle all redirects yourself